# Will my ireland visa from india get rejected since the travel date is passed already?

Tags: visas, ireland

I have submitted my visa application to irish embassy in delhi on 17 oct 2019. And I mentioned date I will be travelling on 4th November and also provided the itinary accordingly. Travel date has already passed for my ireland visa from india but my application is still in process with irish delhi embassy and decision is still pending on it. Will my visa get rejected since its been 2 weeks beyond my travel date mentioned in visa application ?

Comment: What was your reason for the trip? If it was eg to attend a wedding or other fixed date event the fact that the date has now passed may mean a higher chance of refusal. If it was simply tourism then it may not matter too much providing the rest of your application stacks up.

Comment: My application is for attending a job interview in dublin ireland for a company. It is of other type 'Short Stay(c)' visa. The reason I applied on short notice was due to the fact that I got the invitation letter and travel tickets on 12th Oct and they scheduled interview on 4th November.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, since a 'Short Stay (C)' Visa **may** be issued that allows you to enter up to a specific date and then remain up to 90 days.

Applying for a visa on such a short notice was not a good idea.

---

**Visas for Ireland**:

> Make sure to **apply in good time** (see "How to apply" tab below). To be fair to all applicants, applications are processed according to the date on which they are received. If you book a visit to Ireland at short notice, be aware that your visa may not be approved in time.
>
> It takes approximately **6 weeks for a visit visa to be processed**, 4 weeks for applications from spouses of EU citizens and 3 weeks for business visas. If you are hoping to receive your visa before the holidays, **make sure that you have applied in good time**.

---

**Sources**:

- [Visas for Ireland - Department of Foreign Affairs and Trade](https://www.dfa.ie/irish-embassy/germany/our-services/visas/visas-for-ireland/)